# Multiple logins and account association(Not working??)

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, merge-accounts

At my work place I am not able to use Google id to login but for some reason I am able to sign in using Yahoo id. My primary account(reputation wise) is using Google ID and i am having trouble linking these accounts.

**Note**: Followed the below steps mentioned outside of my office network(at home)

I have followed the [steps from this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist) but still not able to combine my accounts. When I go to "My logins" and add more logins -> I login using my google id -> I get redirected to page "**Switch Users on Stack Overflow**" and I quote "Google ID belongs to another user. You can login as **< google id username >** or cancel to stay logged in as **< yahoo id username >**

Please advise how to fix this. I really want to use my primary Google ID user.

Comment: Try logging in using your google ID. You probably have _different_ accounts with the same ID. You may be able and delete it, if not you can ask for it to be merged (you will need the details of both accounts).

Comment: thanks Oded. I have the details of both the accounts. whom shall i write to, to merge the accounts

Comment: @javauser you can reach us via the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page.